# Qt - JNI crash on Android 5

Tags: java, android, c++, qt, java-native-interface

I'm developing an application on Android.  JNI has been crashed since I developed on Android 5. I was debugging and result is , this is part of what I'm getting:

```
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[11,tid=26104,Native,Thread*=0xa1133400,peer=0x12c5b0e0,"QtThread"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[16,tid=26656,Runnable,Thread*=0x9f4b5400,peer=0x1316a5c0,"Thread-111421"]
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void org.qtproject.example.myapplication.MiniXmppService.sendForwardMsg(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int, int)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "QtThread" prio=10 tid=11 Runnable
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5b0e0 self=0xa1133400
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=26104 nice=-11 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xb4fe4580
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 2571059638 546052025 2929 ) utm=216 stm=41 core=3 HZ=100
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0xa129f000-0xa12a1000 stackSize=1012KB
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004640  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00002e8d  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 002457f1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+68)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 0022a377  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+146)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b0b7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+582)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b12b5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 000b432d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1132)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 000bc169  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+20)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #08 pc 00047ebb  /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myapplication-2/lib/arm/libminixmpp.so (CBot::sendForwardMsg(std::string const&, std::string const&, MessageType, MessageState)+54)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #09 pc 00048885  /data/app/org.qtproject.example.myapplication-2/lib/arm/libminixmpp.so (Java_org_qtproject_example_myapplication_MiniXmppService_sendForwardMsg+88)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #10 pc 000194af  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@org.qtproject.example.myapplication-2@base.apk@classes.dex (Java_org_qtproject_example_myapplication_MiniXmppService_sendForwardMsg__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2II+142)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.qtproject.example.myapplication.MiniXmppService.sendForwardMsg(Native method)
F/art     (26030): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.qtproject.example.myapplication.CustomMainActivity.sendForwardMsg(CustomMainActivity.java:1574)
```

I've searched and I found out it's related to *.cpp* file.
here is my code:

**minixmpp.cpp:**

```
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_org_qtproject_example_myapplication_MiniXmppService_sendForwardMsg(
            JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring jid, jstring msg, jint type, jint state)
    {
        std::string sjid;
        jstrToStdStr(env, jid, sjid);
        std::string smsg;
        jstrToStdStr(env, msg, smsg);

        if (g_bot)
            g_bot->sendForwardMsg(sjid, smsg, (MessageType) type, (MessageState) state);
    }
void CBot::sendForwardMsg(const std::string &jid, const std::string &fullContent,
                          MessageType messageType, MessageState state)
{
    if ((!g_continue) || m_env == NULL)
        return;

    jstring jsJid = m_env->NewStringUTF(jid.c_str());
    jstring jsMsg;
    std::string date = "";
    jstring _date = m_env->NewStringUTF(date.c_str());
    std::string nickname = "";
    std::string filePath;
    std::string fileName;
    std::string fileType;
    std::string descriptionText;
    std::string msg;
    std::stringstream fullContentStream(fullContent);

    if (messageType == ImageMessage)
    {
        std::getline(fullContentStream, filePath);

        if (state == Received)
            fileName = filePath.substr(filePath.size() - 36 , 36);
        else
            fileName = filePath;

        filePath = g_outputMediaDir + "image/" + fileName;

        std::string fileExt = fileName.substr(fileName.size() - 3 , 3);

        if (fileExt == "jpg")
            fileType = "image/jpeg";
        else if (fileExt == "png")
            fileType = "image/png";

        std::string line2;
        std::getline(fullContentStream, line2);

        std::string to;

        while (std::getline(fullContentStream, to))
            descriptionText.append(to + "\n");

        unsigned found = descriptionText.find_last_of("\n");

        descriptionText = descriptionText.substr(0, found);

        msg = "<file><type>" + fileType + "</type><url>doi://xmpp.lopl.net/" + fileName +
                "</url><description>" + descriptionText + "</description></file>";

    }
}
```

**EDITED**: I added jstrToStdStr()

```
    void jstrToStdStr(JNIEnv *env, jstring jstr, std::string &str)
{
    const char *s = env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, JNI_FALSE);

    str = s;
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstr, s);
}
```

Is there any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Crashed how?  What other error messages are you getting?  Also post the code for `jstrToStdStr()`.  I suspect that doesn't do what you think.

Comment: I added jstrToStdStr() , and I'm going to report other error messages I'm getting.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Here is other error messages http://www31.speedyshare.com/Kv58h/6cff8822/download/log-crash.txt

Comment: Nitpick: the second argument to `GetStringUTFChars` is a `jboolean*`. So the correct value to pass to signal "I don't care" is `NULL` rather than `JNI_FALSE`. Although they both probably resolve to zero you should use the appropriate define.

Comment: Your logs show failure in `NewStringUTF()`.  Can you tell which one of your calls is failing?  In my experience, when something basic like that happens, you're either passing in bad data, or corrupting something in the JVM via an earlier bad call.  I'd recommend really simplifying your code - since you don't appear to be using the `jstring` and `std::string` arguments.  I also think you're overusing `std::string`.  For example, you create `std::string date = ""` merely to use `date.c_str()` one line later.  Just use the `""` C-style string directly since that's what `NewStringUTF()` accepts.

Comment: @Michael I changed it but it's not solve.

Comment: @AndrewHenle how to convert "" to C-style directly?

Comment: @afn *how to convert "" to C-style directly?*  There's no need - that's what `""` already is.